# IAsyncEnumerable view component return in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have this project that is working fine:

service class:

```
 public async Task<IAsyncEnumerable<ContratoDTO>> ContratoServiceGetAll()
    {
        List<ContratoDTO> listaDeContrato = new List<ContratoDTO>();
        listaDeContrato = await ContratoRepository.GetAllAsync().Result.Select(u => new ContratoDTO(u)).ToList();
        return listaDeContrato.ToAsyncEnumerable();
    }
```

ViewComponent Class:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        ContratoViewModel listaContrato = new ContratoViewModel
        {
            Contratos = await ContratoSerivce.ContratoServiceGetAll()
        };
         return View(listaContrato);
    }
```

and my component on the Shared View folder:

```
   <tbody>
        @if (Model.Contratos != null)
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model.Contratos.ToEnumerable())
            {

                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">@item.NuContrato</th>
                    <td>@item.VlContrato</td>
                    <td>36</td>
                    <td>@item.DtEmissao</td>
                    <td>@item.DtRetorno</td>
                    <td>Rio de Janeiro</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
```

It works but the Model.Contratos.ToEnumerable() is this the best approach ? If i take the ToEnumerable() method out it will throw an error:

```
'Error CS0202: foreach requires that the return type 'IAsyncEnumerator<ContratoDTO>' of 'IAsyncEnumerable<ContratoDTO>.GetEnumerator()' must have a suitable public MoveNext method and public'
```

ps: The ContratoViewModel has a property of IAsyncEnumerable generic type of T my DTO.

Comment: `.Result.Select(u => new ContratoDTO(u)).ToList();` seems to  loose the benefit of using `IAsyncEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

For all the years that I've been using Stack Overflow, this is my first time responding to anyone as I think it's time I should contribute to the community.  I hope this is helpful.

`IAsyncEnumerable<T>` can be awaited on similarly like `Task<T>`.  It doesn't need to be wrapped.  A comment to your question shows that you may lose the benefit of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` if you use `.Result.Select(u => new ContratoDTU(u)).ToList();`.  I agree as `.ToList()` is synchronous and will block until it's completed.

While using the variables in your service class, the following is a shorthanded revision:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<ContratoDTO> ContratoServiceGetAll()
{
    foreach (var u in await ContratoRepository.GetAllAsync())
        yield return new ContratoDTO(u);
}
```

Also, the `.ToEnumerable()` statement in your component (assuming you meant `.AsEnumerable()` from extension method `Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`) will cause the view to block at that moment to execute the `Model.Contractos` query (again, assuming `ContractoRepository.GetAllAsync()` is returning a `IQueryable<T>`).

It's redundant to have `.ToEnumerable()` as the the iteration will begin once `@foreach (var item in Model.Contractos)` is evaluated.